# iconview icon selection appearance

Tags: ruby, gtk, selection

I work on a project using Gtk & Ruby. I want when one icon was selected, it shouldn't seem as a rectangle.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvV33.png

It just seem icon bound was selected. How can supply this?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mD1Ti.png

I use iconview like below:

```
iconview = Gtk::IconView.new
file_store = Gtk::ListStore.new(String, String, TrueClass, Gdk::Pixbuf)
iconview.model = file_store
iconview.text_column = COL_DISPLAY_NAME
iconview.pixbuf_column = COL_PIXBUF
```

How can I code for this appearance?